# How do I pass the value of two separate inputs into the content field of my form in Django?

Tags: django, forms, input, modelform

In my template I have a form that includes two input elements whose values can be adjusted with javascript. I want to be able to take these values and, on form submit, display them in a sentence in a for loop underneath.

index.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'workouts:workout' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="weight">
        <h4>WEIGHT (kgs):</h4>
        <button type="button" class="weight-dec">-</button>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="weight-qty-box" readonly="" name="one">
        <button type="button" class="weight-inc">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="reps">
        <h4>REPS:</h4>
        <button type="button" class="rep-dec">-</button>
        <input type="text" value="0" class="rep-qty-box" readonly="" name="two">
        <button type="button" class="rep-inc">+</button>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit_workout">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>

{% if exercise.workout_set.all %}
    {% for w in exercise.workout_set.all %}
        {{ w.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I have given the form above an action attribute for a url which maps to a view, and each of the inputs has a name in order to access their values in the view. I also have written this form in forms.py:

```
class WorkoutModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ['content']
```

And for context, here is my model:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

My problem from here is that I have no idea how to actually incorporate my model form in my template, or how to write a view that will do what I want it to. I am still new to this and have been searching for an answer for sometime, but so far have not found one. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is able to help you, you should first have a look at the django [Class-Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/) , more specifically the [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview), django already has generic views capable of handling data posted on forms. Your code would look like this:

```
# forms.py
# imports ...
class WorkoutModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ['content']


# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path("test-form/", views.TesteFormView.as_view(), name='test-form'),
]


# views.py
from django.views.generic import FormView
from myapp import forms
from django.contrib import messages

class TesteFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "myapp/index.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:test-form')
    form_class = forms.WorkoutModelForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TesteFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(f"POST DATA =  {self.request.POST}") # debug
        content = form.cleaned_data.get('content')
        # fieldx= form.cleaned_data.get('fieldx')
        # do something whit this fields like :
        Workout.object.create(content=content)
        messages.success(self.request,"New workout object created")

        return super(TesteFormView, self).form_valid(form=self.get_form())

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(f"POST DATA =  {self.request.POST}") # debug
        for key in form.errors:
            messages.error(self.request, form.errors[key])
        return super(TesteFormView, self).form_invalid(form=self.get_form())
```

And your template would look like:

```
# myapp/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TestForm</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I was not aware of the generic class FormView before. Could you please just explain what you mean by fieldx in the commented section? Would this be where I would include my increment/decrement buttons and script tags? Apologies for sounding stupid

Comment: @sgt_pepper85 The fieldx is an hypothetic field and it's means that we can get more data depending on the number of fields in your form, in this case it would be just the content field

Comment: About the buttons, I didn't really understand what the purpose of your application but if weigth and reps are form fields, they should be in forms.py

Comment: Ah ok. Makes sense now. Thank you this helped a lot